# How to make Kentico treat URLs as if folder doesn't exist at all?

Tags: url-rewriting, kentico

So I have a content structure of `Root -> Folder -> Content page`. The natural URL for this is `/foldername/pagename` and I'm trying to figure out how to make it always just `/pagename`.

I can make `/pagename` redirect to `/foldername/pagename` but it still shows as the latter in the address bar. I mucked around with URL rewrites in the web.config and I have this:

```
<rule name="Content" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^Content/(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything. Any ideas how I can setup my Kentico site to treat URLs as if `/foldername` doesn't exist at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways to accomplish this.

- Manually set the URL path on the page. In the Pages application, open the page, and click on the URLs tab. Populate the "Path or pattern" field with the path, e.g. `/pagename`

  [image]
- If you aren't happy with manually setting the URL path, create a [global event handler](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/handling-global-events) to set the correct URL path on document creation (and, perhaps, update of the document). Here's an example:

  ```cs
  [assembly: RegisterModule(typeof(PagePathModule))]
  public class PagePathModule : Module
  {
      public PagePathModule() : base("PagePathModule") { }

      protected override void OnInit()
      {
          DocumentEvents.Insert.After += DocumentInsertAfter;
      }

      private static void DocumentInsertAfter(object sender, DocumentEventArgs e)
      {
          var node = e.Node; // TreeNode of the created document

          var urlPath = "/" + node.DocumentName; // Use the document name as the path

          node.DocumentUseNamePathForUrlPath = false; // Ensure that a custom URL path is used
          node.DocumentUrlPath = TreePathUtils.GetSafeUrlPath(urlPath, node.NodeSiteName); // Set the document URL path
          node.Update();
      }
  }
  ```

  You should make sure you strip out unnecessary characters from the path.

Comment: Can't seem to get the code to run. Do I need to register it in Kentico somewhere for it to work? I assumed classes in the App_Data folder are handled automatically.

http://i.imgur.com/2FBpQoQ.png

Comment: Nevermind! Just found the part that mentions it needs to be in the Old_App_Code folder for Web Applications. It's working now, thanks!